# How to make thread safe program?

Tags: c, multithreading

On a 64-bit architecture pc, the next program should return the result 1.350948.
But it is not thread safe and every time I run it gives (obviously) a different result.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const unsigned int ndiv = 1000;
double res = 0;

struct xval{
  double x;
};

// Integrate exp(x^2 + y^2) over the unit circle on the
// first quadrant.
void* sum_function(void*);
void* sum_function(void* args){
  unsigned int j;
  double y = 0;
  double localres = 0;
  double x = ((struct xval*)args)->x;

  for(j = 0; (x*x)+(y*y) < 1; y = (++j)*(1/(double)ndiv)){
    localres += exp((x*x)+(y*y));
  }

  // Globla variable:
  res += (localres/(double)(ndiv*ndiv));
  // This is not thread safe!
  // mutex? futex? lock? semaphore? other?
}

int main(void){  
  unsigned int i;
  double x = 0;

  pthread_t thr[ndiv];
  struct xval* xvarray;

  if((xvarray = calloc(ndiv, sizeof(struct xval))) == NULL){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for(i = 0; x < 1; x = (++i)*(1/(double)ndiv)){
    xvarray[i].x = x;
    pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, &sum_function, &xvarray[i]);
    // Should check return value.
  }

  for(i = 0; i < ndiv; i++){
    pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
    // If
    // pthread_join(thr[i], &retval);
    // res += *((double*)retval) <-?
    // there would be no problem.
  }

  printf("The integral of exp(x^2 + y^2) over the unit circle on\n\
    the first quadrant is: %f\n", res);

  return 0;
}
```

How can it be thread safe?

**NOTE:** I know that 1000 threads is not a good way to solve this problem, but I really really want to know how to write thread-safe c programs.

Compile the above program with

```
gcc ./integral0.c -lpthread -lm -o integral
```

Comment: Far too broad. Read a tutorial on threads, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for learning to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question (in a comment in the code):

> // mutex? futex? lock? semaphore? other?

Answer: mutex.

See `pthread_mutex_init`, `pthread_mutex_lock`, and `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Answer (score 3):

> pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
>
> // code to make thread safe
>
> pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);

Declare my_mutex either as a global variable like `pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;`. Or initialize in code using `pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;` `pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, NULL);`. Also don't forget to include `#include <pthread.h>` and link your program with `-lpthread` when compiling.

Comment: Declaring the mutex as a global variable will initialize it correctly on some systems, but not on others. To be safe, a global mutex should be declared as `pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`